# Limit block loop?

Tags: ruby, loops, block

I've got the following code...

```
parser = AppleEpf::Parser.new('tmp/incremental/itunes20130410/application')
parser.process_rows { |app|
  Resque.enqueue(AddApp, app)
}
```

Right now, that file (`tmp/incremental/itunes...`) has over 90,000 rows in it. For testing purposes, it'd be nice to limit the `process_rows` block call to just a few rows (say...100).

Is there a way to limit the loop in the block?

For reference, here's the `process_rows` method in the gem:

```
def process_rows(&block)
  File.foreach( @filename, RECORD_SEPARATOR ) do |line|
    unless line[0].chr == COMMENT_CHAR
      line = line.chomp( RECORD_SEPARATOR )
      block.call( line.split( FIELD_SEPARATOR, -1) ) if block_given?
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: You can use `yield` instead of `block.call` if you're talking about the default block supplied to a method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably looking for the `break` command.

Inside any Ruby loop you can put this instruction to stop the execution and return something (or not), so you can use it like:

```
loop do
  do_something_great
  break if some_condition
end
```

To control your execution.

An always welcome link to ruby-doc: http://ruby-doc.org/docs/keywords/1.9/Object.html#method-i-break

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for the `break` keyword.